# ¿Adherir o adherirse?

Tags: verbos, verbo-pronominal

Una de las entradas de *adherir* es la siguiente:

> [**adherir**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=adherir)
>
> *Del lat. adhaerēre 'pegarse, estar adherido'.*
>
> 3. intr. Sumarse o manifestar apoyo a una doctrina, declaración, opinión, etc. *U. m. c. prnl.*

Este sentido es el usado en este titular: *[Las razones de Mockus y López para adherir a Petro](https://www.rcnradio.com/politica/las-razones-de-mockus-y-lopez-para-adherir-petro)* donde se habla de dos personas que se suman a un candidato presidencial.
Mi duda es si el uso del verbo es correcto en el titular. Para mí, sonaría mejor: *Las razones de Mockus y López para adherir**se** a Petro* (O algo como: Ellos **se** adhieren...).

Otros ejemplos:

- [Grupo de oficiales retirados de la policía adhiere a campaña de Petro](http://caracol.com.co/radio/2018/06/14/politica/1529011637_678208.html)
- [Más de 100 líderes ambientalistas adhieren a la campaña de Gustavo Petro](https://www.elespectador.com/elecciones-2018/noticias/politica/mas-de-100-lideres-ambientalistas-adhieren-la-campana-de-gustavo-petro-articulo-794319)

Pero también veo casos en los que se usa como un verbo reflexivo:

- [Clara Rojas **se** adhiere a la campaña presidencial de Iván Duque](http://www.elcolombiano.com/elecciones-2018-colombia/clara-rojas-se-adhiere-a-la-campana-presidencial-de-ivan-duque-LL8841418)
- [UTA Misiones no **se** adhiere al paro de mañana](http://www.primeraedicion.com.ar/nota/275253/uta-misiones-no-se-adhiere-al-paro-de-manana-.html)

¿Tengo en la entrada del DLE toda la información necesaria para determinar cuál forma es correcta?

Comment: Muy interesante tu pregunta. Yo esto me lo había planteado alguna vez, porque en Chile es bien frecuente que los periodistas no usen el pronombre, y me suena raro. Pero no sé si es incorrecto.

Answer (score 9):

En la entrada de [adherir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0jhhl1Z) del DLE tienes un indicio:

> *U. m. c. prnl.* (Usado más como pronominal).

Esto quiere decir que si bien el uso pronominal es más frecuente, ambos usos son correctos. En el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=adherir) dan más detalles:

> 2. Cuando significa ‘sumarse a un dictamen, una propuesta, una opinión, un partido, etc.’, es intransitivo y se construye con un complemento precedido de *a*; puede usarse en forma pronominal —construcción más habitual en España y en gran parte de América— o en forma no pronominal —construcción frecuente en Colombia y en los países del Cono Sur—: *«Un grupo de pintores de muy diversas procedencias se adhieren al nuevo movimiento»* (Colorado Pintura [Esp. 1991]); *«No adhiero a tus teorías»* (Donoso Casa [Chile 1978]).

Comment: En efecto, en Argentina decir "adherir**se** a un movimiento" or "adherir**se** a una teoría" suena hasta gracioso. Sin embargo, cuando se omite el objeto la forma pronominal se acepta, e incluso se acepta con ciertos sustantivos explícitos: ¿Quién adhiere a la huelga? // Yo adhiero (a la huelga) / Yo me adhiero (a la huelga).